# Moderators purposely concealed my question from community discussion and to keep the masses blind

Tags: discussion

I posted this question and it was swept under the rug with no definitive explanation given. I have had many questions in the post, so I don't see how it can be an invalid question. It is related to Judaism, it's a custom that is practiced every year and for some reason they are ashamed for the community to know the truth and discuss this practice. I've had no idea this was going on until today. I acknowledge that I have made it into sort of a rant at first because I was angry and ashamed of my own religion that I have been respecting and following for 26 years, but I quickly edited it to specifically specify what my views and opinions were on the matter so there is no misunderstanding yet it was still deleted.

Here is the deleted link, since you cannot see the question asked, I will post it here as well.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45805/why-is-kaparot-kaparos-being-practiced-meaning-chicken-slaughter

> **This question is a re-post of a question that has been deleted instantly and I don't understand why a Jewish man cannot use this
>   community to figure out something regarding his religion. Why has this
>   question been deleted if it is being practiced by us, we should have
>   nothing to be ashamed of if we do it. If this question gets deleted
>   again you will take a sin on yourself that cannot be cleansed because
>   I will not forgive this. I devoted 26 years of my life respecting the
>   Jewish religion and as soon as I question something about it that has
>   been brushed under the rug all my life from me, my question gets
>   deleted. I guess Jesus was right all along, as soon as he started
>   questioning the Jewish practices aswell he was murdered. There is no
>   difference with what is happening here. How can we even claim to
>   practice a religion if we do not allow free speech regarding the
>   matter?**
>
> Until today, for 26 years this was kept private from me and I was
>   under the impression that the Jewish people do everything right and
>   believe in God but I witnessed something today that has changed my
>   mind and made me shameful of my own heritage as I am half Jewish, as
>   what some people call a broken Jew.
>
> I was walking around today and I heard chicken noises coming from a
>   blue room built with bamboo sticks on top. My first impression was
>   that they have set up a petting zoo for the children because I seen
>   lots and lots of 5-6 year old kids coming in there and standing in
>   line. I look in and I was horrified by the sight of a Rabbi holding
>   two chickens by the neck, the neck was cut and had blood coming out.
>
> I didn't go inside not to absorb any potential negative energy but it
>   seemed to me like some kind of satanic ritual going on as they had
>   people dripping chicken blood on other people in a circular motion
>   while that guy was in some kind of trance.
>
> I know for a fact that God created life and God wouldn't stand for
>   this so my first impression upon seeing this gruesome sight was that
>   this is being done for the devil. I would like if someone here could
>   please explain why this is performed and how this possible can be
>   condoned by God?
>
> For those who are going to down-vote me because you don't believe this
>   is happening, here's a video I found on YouTube of this happening last
>   year very close to where it happened today.
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LGwJEl3Z4E
>
> From this point on, I will no longer consider myself a Jew and only
>   ask that God forgives me for being ignorant for all the years that
>   I've been mislead. I will continue to live by my own religion from now
>   on, unless someone can explain why this is ok.
>
> I believe I know why the Jews do this, my opinion is that it is
>   because the chicken is as innocent as can be, they eat only corn and
>   probably have never even killed a worm in their life so it makes sense
>   to sacrifice one of the most innocent creatures of God to the devil.
>   Also, the chickens have no arms, they cannot defend themselves, they
>   are helpless, they can't even fly. It all makes sense.
>
> Instead of protecting this poor life that does no wrong, Jews do the
>   complete opposite. How can the practice of Kaparot/Kaparos be used to
>   cleanse one of their sins, when committing the act of the ritual is a
>   sin in and of itself? It is mind boggling.
>
> If my question gets suppressed again, be sure of it that I will go to
>   my Rabbi with my father and I will tell him about what is happening
>   here in this community, this is the first time I have been treated
>   this way by my own people.

Comment: It's a little bit insulting to the community here that you think you are the spectacular investigative reporter bringing this hidden practice to light, and the moderators need to hide it from us.  We've all been in the know for a good while now, and not too bothered.  Please tone down your patronizing condescendingness before you come back.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20370/5323 might interest you, as well as other questions under the [tag:kaparot] tag.

Comment: I dont want to know why you do it, I want to know how you guys can believe in God doing this kind of ritual I seen posts where Jews say they wouldn't even harm a fly. So don't tell me that I am ranting when I say it's a satanic ritual because when you say that you are just being ignorance to the facts.

Comment: @SSpoke Whether or not we are being ignorant (we aren't - a brief google search could probably find you some of the meaning behind the ritual, none of which has to do with worshiping Satan), you are ranting.  Ranting is asking a question which includes a tirade which is not relevant to the question.  You could make it not a rant by asking the question without the tirade.  Although, "I don't want to know why you do it" basically is a confession that you have no question, aren't open to hearing answers, and just want to yell.

Answer (score 16):

Stack Exchange is a question and answer site, not a forum ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/266359), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115/266359)) -- there are other places to air complaints. You might want to check out the [help center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help) for advice about what kinds of questions to ask or not to as here.

The post that you placed in blockquotes, above, seems more like a long-winded rant than a question. Yes, there are a few questions in there, as you mentioned, but those were more rhetorical in nature than real questions (eg "*I would like if someone here could please explain why this is performed and how this possible can be condoned by God?*"), which leads me to believe that this is just a "[rant in disguise](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)." I was not involved in the deletion of that question, but I think I might have been because the post, *as written*, is not a question.
There are also many false assumptions in the above post, such as "*this is being done for the devil*," and "*sacrifice one of the most innocent creatures of God to the devil*" -- that is **not** what kapparos is about, and those vindictive assumptions preclude rational answers.
There are also many, many off-topic statements in the post above. For example, "*From this point on, I will no longer consider myself a Jew and only ask that God forgives me for being ignorant for all the years that I've been mislead.*" What does that have to do with anything? Even though this is not part of the question: "*I guess Jesus was right all along, as soon as he started questioning the Jewish practices aswell he was murdered.*" Again, what does this have to do with anything?

Now that I got the hard-to-listen-to part of the answer out of the way, I hope you'll listen to a few pointers on how to ask answerable questions on Mi Yodeya. If I understood you correctly, the kernel of your question was "**What is the significance of the ritual of kapparos?**" So cut out all of the irrelevant discussion about Jesus and the devil, and just simply ask, without any preconceived notions, "What is the significance of the ritual of kapparos?"
If the practice doesn't connect well with a *particular* belief of Judaism that you *know* to be true, you can put that in as an aside -- but just try to keep it focused on your question.
It might be OK to write "*it seemed to me like some kind of satanic ritual going on*" if that's true, but don't make that (incorrect) assumption the basis of your question (in other words, *assume this is a satanic ritual, what is going on??*). You should just ask for a explanation! (*what is the meaning of kapparos?*)

---

And, one thing to note that does not have to do with site policy -- the ritual of kapparos is not one of the basic beliefs of our religion. In fact, many people simply don't do it, or practice it on money instead of on chickens; this, by itself, is not a reason to simply cast aside a rich history of tradition.

---

<sup>And, on the topic of "allow[ing] free speech;" you might want to consider the wise words of Randall Munroe [here](http://xkcd.com/1357/).</sup>

Answer (score 8):

There are a two points that need to be addressed here.

1. Why was your question not a good question?
2. Why was your question deleted? (Since not all bad questions are deleted)

With respect to #1, think about what you would have considered to be a good answer. What kind of answer would you have upvoted and accepted? If the question is composed in such a way that there can be no such answer, it is a bad question.

As far as #2 goes, it is obvious that your post was intended to cause offense. You don't call something a satanic ritual if you're truly interested in learning more. Posts that are intentionally (or even unintentionally) offensive are fair game for deletion.

So what could you have done better? First of all you should realize that just because you didn't know something doesn't mean there is some huge Jewish conspiracy to keep the masses in the dark. Kaparot is a well documented ceremonial act and has never been hidden from Jews or even from non-Jews. So before you ask, do some research. Then, figure out what you really want to know (how can a God who claims to be merciful want this?). Finally, ask the question, making clear exactly what you want to learn and without pre-judging the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess Jesus was right all along, as soon as he started questioning
>   the Jewish practices aswell he was murdered. There is no difference
>   with what is happening here. How can we even claim to practice a
>   religion if we do not allow free speech regarding the matter?

You are sadly mistaken if you think J is the first person to criticize Jewish Practice.  If you look at Numbers 16:1-3 and the whole section following (Parshas Korach) you will find Jewish History replete with events that criticize Jewish Practice.  The sages of the Talmud are not shy of criticizing Jewish practices from the Torah itself (Avrohom Avinu questioning Hashem, Moses hitting the rock etc.)

The fact that you mention J- in your question speaks volumes.  Judaism is a religion that has been around for thousands of years before and after J.  It doesn't take one person who is now dead and six-feet under to change that overnight.

Free-speech in Judaism is only acceptable in the context of knowing and understanding.  We allow criticism by people who actually know what they're talking about.  Do *you* think it's appropriate for a high-school student to make spurious comments about Rocket Scientists or to Ph.D. Professors?  I think not.  The same is true here.  Don't expect answers to questions that are condescending.

> Until today, for 26 years this was kept private from me and I was
>   under the impression that the Jewish people do everything right and
>   believe in God but I witnessed something today that has changed my
>   mind and made me shameful of my own heritage as I am half Jewish, as
>   what some people call a broken Jew.

So *you* don't know the practice.  If you opened any Yom Kippur Machzor you would find the practice.  No-one kept it from you, *you chose* not to see it.  The information has been freely available to anyone who was interested.

Don't use an emotional argument to elicit sympathy. No-one is ever broken from a question, people are broken because of emotional, psychological and issues that take years before they 'break a person'.

> I was walking around today and I heard chicken noises coming from a
>   blue room built with bamboo sticks on top. My first impression was
>   that they have set up a petting zoo for the children because I seen
>   lots and lots of 5-6 year old kids coming in there and standing in
>   line. I look in and I was horrified by the sight of a Rabbi holding
>   two chickens by the neck, the neck was cut and had blood coming out.

Actually this would be entirely wrong.  You made it up, or at least copied it from an antisemitic website.  A chicken that was already slaughtered would never be held up, but immediately put aside to be given to the poor for eating.  Only live chickens are used in the ceremony.

There is no point in addressing the rest of your points.  It is clearly a troll and it is really perfectly reasonable that such a post would be deleted.  This practice is hardly Satanic.  Satanism is an organized religion (albeit highly criticized and controversial). It has ritual practices and a following.  Before you label a particular ritual as 'Satanic' you may wish to follow up with the relevant sources indicating a parallel with Satanic worshippers.  I would think that such a ritual that you "found to be satanic" is your own speculation, and is really troll-baiting.